# IE 11 &nbsp; innerHTML syntax error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am coming across a weird issue with IE. I am using IE 11.0.9600.17107. I cannot put a non breaking space (&nbsp;) in the innerHTML of an element. IE is throwing a syntax error.

```
var e = document.getElementById("debug");
e.innerHTML = "<div>test&nbsp;test</div>; //<-- Syntax error from IE
```

This also affects jquery when using

```
var test = $("<div>test&nbsp;test</div>");
```

This code works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

--EDIT--
So, I did a little more testing. The page that is throwing the javascript syntax error is an ASP.NET MVC page. I can display the page in the browser, view source, copy everything and paste it in a .htm file. When I load that .htm file, everything works fine. To me, that is the exact same HTML and javascript that the offending page runs in IE. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to go from here?

--EDIT 2--
Alright, I did some digging and found that my ASP.NET page was sending back a content type of "application/xhtml+xml" and my html page was "text/html". The content type sent to Firefox and Chrome was "text/html". Once I changed the content-type back to "text/html" the code worked just fine. Can anyone explain why ASP.NET is sending back "application/xhtml+xml" instead of "text/html" and why that matters when trying to set a &nbsp; to the innerHTML through javascript?

Comment: `e.innerHTML = "<div>test&nbsp;test</div>;`  here you missing double quote...  try this `e.innerHTML = "<div>test&nbsp;test</div>";`

Comment: You are missing double quotes `"<div>test&nbsp;test</div>; //<-- Syntax error from IE`

Comment: Sorry. I do have double quotes in my script, just forgot them in the post

Comment: Works just fine on IE 11.0.9600.17126 at my end, of course with proper end-quotes.

Comment: Both work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TSv3K/

Comment: Huh. So I wonder what's causing it on my end. I'm going to start eliminating scripts to see if some other script I have loaded is causing the problem.

Comment: @Pete: How did you manage that fiddle?? It's been down for me since last 6 hours or so!

Comment: Dunno, this is the first one i tried today - must be back up again

Comment: There seems nothing wrong with the code you've described and the situation you have. You might need to do a bit more research before coming back here with a new question.